# Not able to install http module in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, pip

While trying to install http module using pip I am getting below error and not able to solve it.

> pip install http

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'request' (/Users/..../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/request/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's already present in python 3.7 (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.html). You don't need to install it

Answer (score -2):

It's already in python 3.7. No need to install explicitly. But if it is not there or removed accidentally then try this:

`pip3 install http`

Comment: [http on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/http/) is not the official module. It's only for Python 2.6 and 2.7. It's also only in beta. And more generally, stdlib modules aren't on PyPI. You'd have to install them other ways, for example from your package manager on Linux.

Answer (score -2):

re-install python and make sure it's added to your path - do the same for pip too. after that, you're good to go ;)