# `pip install http` throws exit code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

The solution given here: [python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) did not help, both updating pip, and installing ez_setup, did not provide any update, or solution to this problem.

```
D:\TEMP>pip3 install http
Collecting http
  Using cached http-0.02.tar.gz (32 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Luuk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1rec41dp\http_4b80704142254726926ac64be3bf47d0\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          import http
        File "C:\Users\Luuk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1rec41dp\http_4b80704142254726926ac64be3bf47d0\http\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
          from request import Request
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

`python -V` shows "Python 3.11.4"

`pip -V` shows "pip 23.2.1"

`ver` shows: "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2070]"

Any guidance needed on how to install this package.

Comment: What is your current version of pip?

Comment: updated version info.

Comment: does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55075816/13642249) help? Looks to be included already

Comment: @kyrlon: Yes, this solves: "It's already present in python 3.7+ (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.html). You don't need to install it"